# How to filter date using Query function in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have prepared a [sheet][1]

[1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tBvUfjgnvoLEEPMI7PiMofJ4a8fjA1asAyIN4AX668I/edit#gid=0  , I want to remove the row where date is less than today. I have build a formula for that,

```
=QUERY(A2:F1000,"select A where C > 17 Aug 2023'")
```

but unfortunately, it is not working. So, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=QUERY(A2:F,"Where C is not null AND C > date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

OR

```js
=filter(A:F,C:C>today(),C:C<>"")
```

Comment: At S. No. 97 (98 as per sheet row no.) Dates are greater than today but not reflect. Please correct this also.

Comment: changed formula to only reflect **rows greater than today** based on  `Column C` dates